# What is MySQL doing? There are no active queries and full utilization of disk

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds

I see an abnormal behavior of disk IOPS being fully utilized constantly for hours without no actual queries within this time range.

I have MariaDB 10.4.21 running in AWS RDS at db.t4g.medium machine.

Attached are images of RDS metrics where constant load is clearly visible, and image of processlist which show zero activity.

How can I trace what MySQL is doing?

[image: Metrics for the past hour]
[image: Processlist]

Comment: did you find out? we're having the same issue

Comment: @Raphael Yes, AWS support responded me back then that MySQL was doing some sort of vacuum of leftovers of old transactions. From where we got it, if VM is small, this process takes considerable time, and there is not much you can do it about it.